# How do I use the riscv-tests suite?

Tags: testing, benchmarking, riscv

I have (eventually) worked out how to build the riscv-test suite, but how do I use it?

I can obviously run the different benchmarks like this:

```
spike dhrystone.riscv
```

But how do I access the different test virtual machines? All the different pieces seem to be built under the `isa` directory - but how do I use them in such a way I get meaningful output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to go to the `isa` directory and `make run`.

Essentially this generates a lot of empty files if your ISA is behaving properly.